# What is the difference between Runas_List and User_List in sudoers file on Linux

Tags: linux, sudo

I have gone through the [man page](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.7.10/sudoers.man.html) and it states the following:

> A Runas_List is similar to a User_List except that instead of User_Aliases it can contain Runas_Aliases

Looking at the definition of `User_Aliases` and  `Runas_Aliases` I see no material difference between the, either, as they are in-turn defined using `User_List` and `Runas_List` respectively

Comment: Runas_Alias allows the inclusion of uids whereas User_Alias does not.

Comment: @DravSloan that isn't true looking at the man page. Both allow inclusion of UIDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user list can be used to define which users are allowed to run sudo.

The Runas list can be used to define the accounts an authorized user can "run commands as".

```
User_Alias ADMINS = %admin, root
Runas_Alias SERVICES = apache, tomcat
ADMINS ALL=(SERVICES) ALL
```

Would allow users of the admin group and root run any command as either apache or tomcat

```
sudo -u apache whatever
```